# SQL query distinct, inner or join 2 columns of same table and display all fields

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, union, distinct

I'm developing a WP plugin and I have a table with ids, name, surname, mobile and phone

I want to execute a query which **distinct mobile** and **phone** values, and they are not null
among with the other fields

[image: Check table fields]

and i want to display as following image

[image: Need this result]

So far I have this query which displays a list with all unique mobile and phone combined to 1 column

```
$qry ="SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (SELECT it.phone AS 'phone'
        FROM table_name it
    UNION ALL
    SELECT itt.mobile AS 'mobile'
        FROM table_name itt  
) AS a";
```

Also tried this but not works

```
    $qry ="SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM (SELECT it.mobile AS 'mobile',
                it.smsgroup_id AS 'smsgroup_id',
                it.name AS 'name',
                it.surname AS 'surname',
                it.phone AS 'phone'
            FROM $table_name it
WHERE it.mobile != ''
        UNION ALL
        SELECT itt.mobile AS 'mobile',
                itt.smsgroup_id AS 'smsgroup_id',
                itt.name AS 'name',
                itt.surname AS 'surname',
                itt.phone AS 'phone'
            FROM $table_name rt
                INNER JOIN $table_name itt ON itt.smsgroup_id = rt.smsgroup_id
    ) AS a";
```

Comment: what error message did you get?

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron (or a tautology, depending on your point of view)

Comment: I don't get error. I just cant combine mobile and phone columns to 1. Then remove duplicated values and display remaining columns

Answer (score 0):

`union` (as opposed to `union all`) applies a uniqueness:

```sql
SELECT name, surname, phone
FROM   mytable
UNION
SELECT name, surname, mobile
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: @IliasBenetos arg, I explicitly wrote that `union` should be used instead of `union all`, and then out of habit used `union all`... Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT 

KashifSolangi.Named AS Named,
KashifSolangi.surname AS surname,
KashifSolangi.phone  AS phone_no,
IF (  KashifSolangi.mobile = KashifSolangi.phone,  NULL, KashifSolangi.mobile ) AS Mobile_no


    FROM 
    (

        SELECT 'Kashif Mustafa' AS Named, 'Solangi' AS surname, 155 AS mobile, 155 as phone
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Saqaf Mustafa' AS Named, 'Solangi Qazi' AS surname, 200 AS mobile, 146 AS phone
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Ghulam Mustafa' AS Named, 'Solangi Khan' AS surname, 120 AS mobile, 120 AS phone
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Arif Solangi' AS Named,'Solangi Lahoti' AS surname,  NULL AS mobile, 130 AS phone

    ) AS KashifSolangi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot using `union all` (although MySQL supports lateral joins in the most recent version).

Just filter out the empty rows:

```
(SELECT name, surname, phone
 FROM table_name it
 WHERE phone <> ''
) UNION ALL
(SELECT name, surname, mobile
 FROM mytable it
 WHERE phone <> ''
)
```